# Azure Speech To Text SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromAuthorizationToken() Not Working

Tags: javascript, azure, speech-to-text

When trying to use Speech to Text, I always get a Websocket Error on Chrome when using this code:

```
const audioConfig = SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromStreamInput(stream);

          const config = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromAuthorizationToken(
            "YOUR_SPEECH_API(?)",
            "YOUR_REGION"
          );
          config.speechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US";

          recognition = new SpeechSDK.SpeechRecognizer(config, audioConfig);

          recognition.startContinuousRecognitionAsync();
```

I have tried to try any subscription key I know of (LUIS, Cognitive Speech, Subscription from API Manager), but nothing seems to work. I believe that:`fromAuthorizationToken()` is wrong, but I don't know with what method to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

- Well instead of `fromAuthorizationToken()` you can use the `fromSubscription()` for authorization.
- Now `fromSubscription()` takes the`KEY` and `REGION` as parameter. Both can be found in the portal.

[image]

- Now code should Look like this :

```
const  speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription("<YOUR KEY>", "<REGION>");
speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US";

let  audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromStreamInput(InputStream);

let  recognizer = new  sdk.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

recognizer.recognizeOnceAsync(result  => {
    console.log(`RECOGNIZED: Text=${result.text}`);
    recognizer.close();
});
```

- Here I am running this in a console app and getting the following output without any error :
  [image]